# What is the right way to treat Python argparse.Namespace() as a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, duck-typing

If I want to use the results of `argparse.ArgumentParser()`, which is a `Namespace` object, with a method that expects a dictionary or mapping-like object (see [collections.Mapping](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Mapping)), what is the right way to do it?

```
C:\>python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 10 2012, 23:31:26) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win
32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import argparse
>>> args = argparse.Namespace()
>>> args.foo = 1
>>> args.bar = [1,2,3]
>>> args.baz = 'yippee'
>>> args['baz']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'Namespace' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
>>> dir(args)
['__class__', '__contains__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '_
_format__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__module__', '__ne__',
'__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__
', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_get_args', '_get_kwargs', 'ba
r', 'baz', 'foo']
```

**Is it proper to "reach into" an object and use its `__dict__` property?**

I would think the answer is no: `__dict__` smells like a convention for implementation, but not for an interface, the way `__getattribute__` or `__setattr__` or `__contains__` seem to be.

Comment: Did you try `dict(args)`? Why wouldn't the obvious way work?

Comment: @CharlieParker Did **you** try it? It raises `TypeError: 'Namespace' object is not iterable`.

Answer (score 618, accepted):

You can access the namespace's dictionary with [*vars()*](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#vars):

```
>>> import argparse
>>> args = argparse.Namespace()
>>> args.foo = 1
>>> args.bar = [1,2,3]
>>> d = vars(args)
>>> d
{'foo': 1, 'bar': [1, 2, 3]}
```

You can modify the dictionary directly if you wish:

```
>>> d['baz'] = 'store me'
>>> args.baz
'store me'
```

Yes, it is okay to access the __dict__ attribute.  It is a well-defined, tested, and guaranteed behavior.

Comment: The docs say: "The returned dictionary should not be modified: the effects on the corresponding symbol table are undefined." Which *may* only refer to the behavior of `vars()` (which is either `locals()` or `globals()`), but I'm not really sure.

Comment: hmm, I guess I don't really understand the difference between using `vars()` and `__dict__`

Comment: @delnan Someone had made an incorrect edit to the docs and made an over-broad admonition.  The docs were subsequently corrected.  See  http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#vars  While there are some special cases that have read-only dictionaries (such as locals and class dictionary proxies), the rest of the cases are updateable.  The *vars(obj)* call is synonymous with obj.__dict__.  In the case of an *argparse* namespace, *vars(args)* gives direct access to an updateable dictionary.

Comment: Worth pointing out that going the `vars` route retains the order the arguments were defined by the parser unlike `dict(args._get_kwargs())`

Comment: why doesn't the obvious way work e.g. `dict(args)`? Or at least why is this not the top answer/recommended?

Comment: @CharlieParker The *dict()* constructor builds new dictionaries from a list of tuples or from keyword arguments.  In contrast, the *vars()* builtin accesses the \__dict__ attribute to retrieve existing dictionaries enclosed by various objects include an argparse namespace.

Comment: I'm doing this so I can use slick pattern matching from https://peps.python.org/pep-0636 with a namespace from argparse. thus you get `match vars(parser.parse_args()) ...`, which is pretty slick, but it seems like a clooge. I'd rather have a static-type-ee way of destructuring. Put thoughts here: https://gist.github.com/Groostav/0968a3c32f5d9a1a0eb121c9133653bf. Given that a Namespace type is a kind've simple type on top of a dict, I would've thought it would destructure more nicely.

Answer (score 127):

[Straight from the horse's mouth](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#the-namespace-object):

> If you prefer to have dict-like view of the attributes, you can use the standard Python idiom, [`vars()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#vars):
>
> ```
> >>> parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
> >>> parser.add_argument('--foo')
> >>> args = parser.parse_args(['--foo', 'BAR'])
> >>> vars(args)
> {'foo': 'BAR'}
> ```
>
> — The Python Standard Library, 16.4.4.6. [The Namespace object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#the-namespace-object)

Comment: Still 'foo' misses '--'. Any idea to that?

Comment: @user2678074 this is intentional to match shell flags. The dashes are extraneous inside python execution.

Comment: `vars(args)` gives me `TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable`

Comment: @user5359531 you probably overwrote the global `vars` with a variable. You can use `__builtins__.vars` to access it directly, or `del vars` to stop shadowing it.

Comment: @NickT Minor correction: Python functions are statically scoped so if you shadow a global variable in a function, that identifier will always refer to the local variable within that function, even before it's assigned or after `del`.  At the module scope `del` _will_ work to "un-shadow" builtins.

Comment: why doesn't the obvious way work e.g. `dict(args)`? Or at least why is this not the top answer/recommended?

Answer (score 2):

Note that if you're trying to treat args as a dict to find out if it has an attribute, you can just do the following instead:

```
if hasattr(args, 'someProperty'):
    a.someProperty
```

more info on [hasattr](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#hasattr) and [similar answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/610893/26510)

Also, you can get the value if you prefer using the similar [getattr method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr):

```
value = getattr(args, 'someProperty')
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is it proper to "reach into" an object and use its **dict** property?

In general, I would say "no". However `Namespace` has struck me as over-engineered, possibly from when classes couldn't inherit from built-in types.

On the other hand, `Namespace` does present a task-oriented approach to argparse, and I can't think of a situation that would call for grabbing the `__dict__`, but the limits of my imagination are not the same as yours.

Comment: It is perfectly okay to access the \_\_dict\_\_ attribute.  Introspection is fundamental to the language.  The attribute was made public for a reason :-)

Comment: But everything in Python is "public". There are no distinctions (except the leading underscore convention) between the implementation variables used in an instance, and the public interface it presents. Especially in a dictionary-like object: the line between instance methods, and dictionary values which are functions, is a bit blurry.

Comment: If you're passing the arguments as named parameters? `do_something(**args.__dict__)`

Comment: why doesn't the obvious way work e.g. `dict(args)`? Or at least why is this not the top answer/recommended?

Comment: A reason to grab the `__dict__` would be for logging purposes as `Object of type Namespace is not JSON serializable`