# How to iterate over arguments

Tags: python, argparse

I have such script:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
                description='Text file conversion.'
                )
parser.add_argument("inputfile",   help="file to process", type=str)
parser.add_argument("-o", "--out", default="output.txt",
                    help="output name")
parser.add_argument("-t", "--type", default="detailed",
                    help="Type of processing")

args = parser.parse_args()

for arg in args:
    print(arg)
```

But it doesnt work. I get error:

```
TypeError: 'Namespace' object is not iterable
```

How to iterate over arguments and their value?

Answer (score 141, accepted):

Add `vars` if you want to iterate over a `Namespace` object:

```
 for arg in vars(args):
     print arg, getattr(args, arg)
```

Comment: In Python 3:

for arg in vars(args):
     print(arg, getattr(args, arg))

Answer (score 34):

[`Namespace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argparse.Namespace) objects aren't iterable, the standard docs suggest doing the following if you want a dictionary:

```
>>> vars(args)
{'foo': 'BAR'}
```

So

```
for key, value in vars(args).items():
    # do stuff
```

To be honest, I am not sure why you want to iterate over the arguments. That somewhat defeats the purpose of having an argument parser.

Comment: a typical usage for this is implementing a `debug-input` mode where a script prints out all the input arguments and exits; useful for stuff like making sure datetime input values got interpreted correctly

Comment: Note, `iteritems()` in Python 2.x, `items()` in Python 3.x.

Comment: With regards to the last remark, you could have a metaprogram that parses command line arguments based on a configuration file

Comment: also for debugging purposes to print a list of all args

Answer (score 9):

After

```
args = parser.parse_args()
```

to display the arguments, use:

```
print args # or print(args) in python3
```

The `args` object (of type `argparse.Namespace`) isn't iterable (i.e. not a list), but it has a `.__str__` method, which displays the values nicely.

`args.out` and `args.type` give the values of the 2 arguments you defined.  This works most of the time.  `getattr(args, key)` the most general way of accessing the values, but usually isn't needed.

```
vars(args)
```

turns the namespace into a dictionary, which you can access with all the dictionary methods.  This is spelled out in the `docs`.

ref: the Namespace paragraph of the docs - https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#the-namespace-object

Comment: Thanks for the nice write up!

Answer (score 3):

I'm using `args.__dict__`, which lets you access the underlying dict structure.
Then, its a simple key-value iteration:

```
for k in args.__dict__:
  print k, args.__dict__[k]
```

Answer (score 3):

Parsing the _actions from your parser seems like a decent idea. Instead of running parse_args() and then trying to pick stuff out of your Namespace.

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
                description='Text file conversion.')
parser.add_argument("inputfile", help="file to process", type=str)
parser.add_argument("-o", "--out", default="output.txt",
                help="output name")
parser.add_argument("-t", "--type", default="detailed",
                help="Type of processing")
options = parser._actions
for k in options:
    print(getattr(k, 'dest'), getattr(k, 'default'))
```

You can modify the 'dest' part to be 'choices' for example if you need the preset defaults for a parameter in another script (by returning the options in a function for example).

Answer (score 1):

Using the builtin `dict()` class to iterate over the args is straightforward and works great:

```
args = parser.parse_args()
args_dict = dict(vars(args))
for i, ii in args_dict.items():
     print(i, ii)
```

From `builtins.py`:

```
    def __init__(self, seq=None, **kwargs): # known special case of dict.__init__
        """
        dict() -> new empty dictionary
        dict(mapping) -> new dictionary initialized from a mapping object's
            (key, value) pairs
        dict(iterable) -> new dictionary initialized as if via:
            d = {}
            for k, v in iterable:
                d[k] = v
        dict(**kwargs) -> new dictionary initialized with the name=value pairs
            in the keyword argument list.  For example:  dict(one=1, two=2)
        # (copied from class doc)
        """
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

`ArgumentParser.parse_args` returns a `Namespace` object instead of an iterable arrays.

For your reference, https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#parsing-arguments

```
ArgumentParser parses arguments through the parse_args() method. This will inspect the command line, convert each argument to the appropriate type and then invoke the appropriate action.
```

And it is not supposed to be used like that. Consider your use case, in the doc, it says *`argparse` will figure out how to parse those out of `sys.argv`.*, which means you don't have to iterate over those arguments.