# Print command line arguments with argparse?

Tags: python, python-2.7, argparse

I am using `argparse` to parse command line arguments.

To aid debugging, I would like to `print` a line with the arguments which with the Python script was called. Is there a simple way to do this within `argparse`?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

[`ArgumentParser.parse_args`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.parse_args) by default takes the arguments simply from [`sys.argv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.argv). So if you don’t change that behavior (by passing in something else to `parse_args`), you can simply print `sys.argv` to get all arguments passed to the Python script:

```
import sys
print(sys.argv)
```

Alternatively, you could also just print the namespace that `parse_args` returns; that way you get all values in the way the argument parser interpreted them:

```
args = parser.parse_args()
print(args)
```

Comment: This does not works if `parser.parse_args()` require mandatory arguments. Is there an alternative in this case ?

Answer (score 30):

If running ***argparse within another python script*** (e.g. inside [unittest](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18161115/658497)), then printing ***sys.argv*** will only print the arguments of the main script, e.g.:

> ['C:\eclipse\plugins\org.python.pydev_5.9.2.201708151115\pysrc\runfiles.py', 'C:\eclipse_workspace\test_file_search.py', '--port', '58454', '--verbosity', '0']

In this case you should use [vars](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#vars) to iterate over argparse args:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(...
...
args = parser.parse_args()
for arg in vars(args):
    print arg, getattr(args, arg)
```

Thanks to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27181165/658497

Comment: I would use a print call like the following
`print(' {} {}'.format(arg, getattr(args, arg) or ''))` with `getattr(args, arg) or ''` being the essential difference to your version to prevent the word 'None' from being printed in case of unused optional parameters.

Answer (score 16):

You can get the arguments as a `dict` by calling `vars(args)`
Then you can iterate over the key-value pairs of the `dict`

```
args = parser.parse_args()
print(' '.join(f'{k}={v}' for k, v in vars(args).items()))
```

Comment: `vars` can be replace by `__dict__`. `for k, v in args.__dict__.items():print(f"{k}: {v}")`
`