# Python 2.x optionnal subparsers - Error too few arguments

Tags: python, python-2.7, argparse

I have been trying to set up a main parser with two subs parser so that when called alone, the main parser would display a help message.

```
def help_message():
    print "help message"

import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(dest='sp')

parser_a = subparsers.add_parser('a')
parser_a.required = False
#some options...
parser_b = subparsers.add_parser('b')
parser_b.required = False
#some options....

args = parser.parse_args([])

if args.sp is None:
    help_message()
elif args.sp == 'a':
    print "a"
elif args.sp == 'b':
    print "b"
```

This code works well on Python 3 and I would like it to work aswell on Python 2.x

I am getting this when running 'python myprogram.py'

```
myprogram.py: error: too few arguments
```

Here is my question : How can i manage to write 'python myprogram.py' in shell and get the help message instead of the error.

Comment: What might the question be?

Comment: I've never seen sub parsers marked as optional, and I don't see anything in the docs to suggest this is supported. Given that you would get a help message if you omitted the required subcommand, I'm not sure I see why it is useful to allow an optional subcommand.

Comment: You're also duplicating a lot of functionality that is already built into ``argparse``. It already has all the facilities for displaying help messages when required arguments are left out.

Comment: Well the message I want to display is to present the whole functionnalities to a newcomer, this program will be used by non-informatics-oriented people so they will type the program name. I want them to have a full program explanation by doing this instead of expecting them to type 'python myprogram -h' then 'python myprogram a -h' and 'python myprogram b -h'.

Thing is that Python 3 will run the function help_message() and Python 2 will display an error and i'd like to overcome it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you are dealing the bug discussed in http://bugs.python.org/issue9253

Your `subparsers` is a positional argument.  That kind of argument is always required, unless `nargs='?'` (or *).  I think that is why you are getting the error message in 2.7.

But in the latest py 3 release, the method of testing for required arguments was changed, and subparsers fell through the cracks.  Now they are `optional` (not-required).  There's a suggested patch/fudge to make `argparse` behave as it did before (require a subparser entry).  I expect that eventually py3 argparse will revert to the py2 practice (with a possible option of accepting a `required=False` parameter).

So instead of testing `args.sp is None`, you may want to test `sys.argv[1:]` before calling `parse_args`.  `Ipython` does this to produce it's own help message.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I did not consider not calling parse_args() immediately. I added a new argparse.Namespace object and i overcome the problem with that and the sys.argv[1:] as you said. If anyone wants to do the same check this [url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16878315/what-is-the-right-way-to-treat-python-argparse-namespace-as-a-dictionary)

Comment: BOOM! Solution also applies to the Java version, argparse4j, just add .nargs("?") to subcommand parameters

Answer (score 0):

For others - I ended up on this page while trying to figure out why I couldn't just call my script with no arguments while using argparse in general.

[The tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/argparse.html#id1) demonstrates that the difference between an **optional** argument and a **required** argument is adding "**--**" to the name:

```
parser.add_argument("--show")  <--- Optional arg
parser.add_argument("show")    <--- Not optional arg
```