# how do I get: prog.py [-h] [foo [-p bar]]

Tags: python, argparse

How do I setup a argparse.ArgumentParser() to get an optional argument (-p bar) that needs an [optional] positional argument (foo) ?

The program should accept:

- prog.py
- prog.py foo
- prog.py foo -p bar

But it should not accept:

- prog.py -p bar

This is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import argparse

def setupArgParser():
  desc="tun0graf"
  parser=argparse.ArgumentParser(description=desc)
  parser.add_argument('logfilename',  nargs='?', help='name of a logfile')
  parser.add_argument('-s', dest='snapname', nargs=1,
               help='create snapshot of logfilename and save it as snapname.png')
  return(parser.parse_args())


arg=setupArgParser()

print "logfilename", arg.logfilename
print "snapname", arg.snapname
```

Comment: Where is your attempt, and what exactly is wrong with it? This isn't a code-writing service.

Comment: Sounds like you want to support a [sub-parser](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#sub-commands).

Comment: sub-parser wont work, because all my arguments are optional. And these sub-parser sub-commands are fixed text.
For me it seems that argparse does not support [arg1 [-p arg2]] and the same for [arg1] | [arg1 -p arg2].

Comment: Due to a bug, in the latest release, subparsers are optional.  But for 2.7 they are required.  Until my UsageGroup goes in, you need to write your test to be run after parse_args.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This modification to your function should do the trick:

```
def setupArgParser():
    desc="tun0graf"
    usage = '%(prog)s [-h] [logfilename [-s SNAPNAME]]'
    parser=argparse.ArgumentParser(description=desc, usage=usage)
    parser.add_argument('logfilename',  nargs='?', help='name of a logfile')
    parser.add_argument('-s', dest='snapname', nargs=1,
               help='create snapshot of logfilename and save it as snapname.png')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    # test
    if args.logfilename is None and args.snapname is not None:
        parser.error('SNAPNAME can only be used with logfilename')
    return args
```

I am testing for the interaction of the 2 arguments after parsing.  And I am using a custom `usage`.  With this, giving a `-s name` without a filename produces:

```
usage: stack24219021.py [-h] [logfilename [-s SNAPNAME]]
stack24219021.py: error: SNAPNAME can only be used with logfilename
```

Without the custom usage, we get:

```
usage: stack24219021.py [-h] [-s SNAPNAME] [logfilename]
```

That's because the `parser` knows nothing about the interaction of the 2 arguments, and it normally puts `positional` arguments after the `optionals` (the ones with `-`).

---

This does look like a case for subparsers, except that you want `logfilename` to be optional.  As discussed in the recent https://stackoverflow.com/a/24211480/901925 in Py2.7 this is not possible.  In the latest Py3 release subparsers are optional, but that's a bug that will be changed (though it may still be possible to flag them as optional).

There is talk about extending the `Mutually_exclusive_group` mechanism to allow more general tests like yours. Your example would be a good test case.  But the test I wrote above is simpler than anything that can be done with the proposed `groups`.