# Error : Too few arguments in Google Maps API Python client

Tags: python, google-maps

I installed the Google Maps API client for python on Mac OS with Python 2.7 .

I got the client ID and client secret. I tried running one of the samples Google has uploaded, that is the Coordinate sample. Found here -> https://code.google.com/p/google-api-python-client/source/browse/samples/coordinate/coordinate.py

When I run it, I get the error

```
coordinate.py: error: too few arguments
```

I'm new to using Google APIs. Any pointers on what arguments I need to pass? I update my code and client_secretes.json with my Client ID.

Comment: would be helpful to inform us which **line** raises the error, please post the full traceback

Comment: It does not show any line number. Simple coordinate.py: error: too few arguments

@EdChum

Comment: You might want to try your code in Python 3.x, it might be an issue in python 2.x: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24207750/python-2-x-optionnal-subparsers-error-too-few-arguments

Comment: @ztan I tried running with Python 3.4. I get the syntax error  at line 94
    except AccessTokenRefreshError, e:
                                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

This is a sample program and Google API page says Python 2.7 or 2.6 is required and I earlier tried it with Python 2.7.5