# How to specify arguments in the form of `input=<INPUT>` in argparse

Tags: python, argparse

I could use [argparse](https://pypi.org/project/argparse/) to add command line arguments in the form of

- `-i <INPUT>` or
- `--input <INPUT>`.

I want to instead have the command be in the form of `input=<INPUT>`.

#### Code

What I currently have:

```py
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-i', '--input', help = "Input is a required field", required = True)
```

#### Issue

When I change `'--input'` to `'input='` it doesn't work.

#### Question

How to specify the format so that 'input=' followed by the input string can be given as valid command line argument?

Comment: with your current configuration you can do `--input=...`.  Arguments without a prefix are reserved for positional arguments

Comment: Short of rewriting significant portions of `argparse` itself, you can't have a positional  argument like `input=foo` be recognized as a form of `--input=foo`. If it's required, I would suggest making it a positional argument. You could require that it be provided in the form of `input=foo` via a custom `type` argument to `add_argument`, but that would be redundant because it wouldn't let you specify different arguments in an arbitrary order.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27146262/create-variable-key-value-pairs-with-argparse-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to explicitly ask for support of `=`. It should just work.

```
>>> import argparse
>>>
>>> parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
>>> parser.add_argument('-i', '--input', help = "Input is a required field", required = True)
_StoreAction(option_strings=['-i', '--input'], dest='input', nargs=None, const=None, default=None, type=None, choices=None, required=True, help='Input is a required field', metavar=None)
>>> parser.parse_args(['--input=foobar'])
Namespace(input='foobar')
>>>
```

If you want to get rid of the double dashes too, you may have to write your own argument parsing code. I don't see any documentation suggesting it's supported. You can replace dash with something else using [prefix_chars](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#prefix-chars), but you can't completely get rid of it.