# How does one configure and parse an argparse argument such as -x option=value?

Tags: python, type-conversion, argparse

Python novice here.
I am attempting to set up an argument in argparse that takes the form of "-x option=value -x option2=value..."

I'm using the following which passes the arguments.

```
swlist_parser.add_argument("-x", nargs="+",action='append',metavar='option',
              help="-x option=value, set the option to value")
```

I have a dictionary of default arguments that are available for the command.
I want to use -x option=value to modify the dictionary of default arguments with the one on the command line.

swlist -x distribution_target_directory=/tmp -x admin_directory=/var/lib/sw -x another_option=another_value ...

```
# Code I have
# args.x is now the following:
   if args.x != None:
       print("-x options passed: ")
       cliopts = {}
       for opt in (args.x):
           print(opt)
```

-x options passed:

```
['distribution_target_directory=/tmp']
['admin_directory=/var']
```

The arguments to -x are now class 'list'.  I need a solution to add these to a dictionary.

I tried modifying the argparse to be dictionary.  This option doesn't allow for the option=value

```
swlist_parser.add_argument("-x", nargs="+",action='append',type=dict,metavar='option', help="-x option=value, set the option to value")
```

```
swlist.py  -x distribution_target_directory=/tmp -x admin_directory=/var  -X /home/pweber/pauls.defaults

usage: swlist [options] [software_selections] [@ target_selections]
swlist: error: argument -x: invalid dict value: 'distribution_target_directory=/tmp'
```

The expected output would allow for this code to add the options to a dicitonary

```
    if args.x != None:
        print("-x options passed: ")
        cliopts = {}
        for opt in (args.x):
            # convert option=value to dictionary`your text`
            cliopts = cliopts|<opt converted to dict>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create variable key/value pairs with argparse (python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27146262/create-variable-key-value-pairs-with-argparse-python)

Comment: you get the error because `dict('admin_directory=/var')` is not a valid way to use the `dict` function.  Remember, `type` is a **function** that takes a string argument.

Comment: If `args.x` is a list of strings, split each on '=' and add each to a doct.

Comment: Yes @AbdulAzizBarkat that article is exactly what I was searching for.  I was serching for 'option=value' vs Key=Value.  I would have found it sooner and not needed to post.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have a list `ls` with entries separated by `=`, you can do :
 `{arr[0]:arr[1] for x in ls if len(arr:=x.split('='))==2 }`

To create a dictionary using list compherension.

Answer (score 0):

In order to handle multiple `-x`, we can use a custom `argparse.Action`:

```py
import argparse


class KeyValueAction(argparse.Action):
    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
        # Extract the current dictionary from the namespace
        # or create a new one
        dict_object = getattr(namespace, self.dest) or {}
        setattr(namespace, self.dest, dict_object)

        dict_object.update(kv.split("=", 1) for kv in values)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("-x", nargs="*", action=KeyValueAction)
    options = parser.parse_args()
    x = options.x
    print(x)
```

Here is a sample interaction:

```bash
$ python3 swlist.py -x distribution_target_directory=/tmp -x admin_directory=/var
{'distribution_target_directory': '/tmp', 'admin_directory': '/var'}
```

## Notes

- The heart of a custom action is the `__call__` function
- In this function, we are given a namespace object. The first two lines make sure that if we have not set the attribute `self.dest` (which is the string 'x' in this case, then we should set it to an empty dictionary.
- The `.update` call splits each value by the equal sign and update the dictionary
- After calling `parse_args`, `options.x` will be a dictionary with all the keys/values defined from the command line.