# argparse: map user input to defined constant

Tags: python, python-2.7, argparse

I'd like to build a `parser.add_argument(...)` to map given argument with constant defined in my code.

Suppose I have the following

```
import argparse

# Both are the same type
CONST_A = <something>
CONST_B = <otherthing>

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument(...)

# I'd like the following to be true:
parser.parse_args("--foo A".split()).foo == CONST_A
parser.parse_args("--foo B".split()).foo == CONST_B
```

What can I put in lieu of `...`?

---

The best I could do with `const` was:

```
import argparse

# Both are the same type
CONST_A = 10
CONST_B = 20

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
status_group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True)
status_group.add_argument("-a", const=CONST_A, action='store_const')
status_group.add_argument("-b", const=CONST_B, action='store_const')

# I'd like the following to be true:
print parser.parse_args("-a".split()).a == CONST_A # True
print parser.parse_args("-b".split()).b == CONST_B # True
```

Note that the constants are saved into tw odifferent attributes `a` and `b`, witch suits me not :(

Comment: have you executed `help(argparse)` or checked out the documentation? (https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) I am looking into it for the first time now.

Comment: I have, but it's a bit hairy for a beginner. BTW, I'm writing python2 code.

Comment: There are `const` and `default` parameters to `add_argument`. Experiment with those.

Comment: @Evert the best I could do with `const` and `action="store_const"` was to map my constants into two different attribute of returned namespace.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The simplest way is to take advantage of the `type=` option in `add_argument` like [@hpaulj](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35648071/argparse-map-user-input-to-defined-constant/35658444#35658444) did although it can be generalized with a factory function:

```
def argconv(**convs):
    def parse_argument(arg):
        if arg in convs:
            return convs[arg]
        else:
            msg = "invalid choice: {!r} (choose from {})"
            choices = ", ".join(sorted(repr(choice) for choice in convs.keys()))
            raise argparse.ArgumentTypeError(msg.format(arg,choices))
    return parse_argument
```

then in lieu of `...` just use `type=argconv(A=CONST_A, B=CONST_B)`:

```
parser.add_argument("--foo", type=argconv(A=CONST_A, B=CONST_B))
```

And then everything will work as you want it to in your example.

---

The following is the first answer I posted, it is still valid but isn't nearly as simple as the above solution.

An alternate method is to make a class that inherits from `argparse.ArgumentParser` and override `parse_args` to modify the result as it is generated:

```
import argparse

class MappedParser(argparse.ArgumentParser):
    mapping = {} #backup if you don't use def_mapping

    def def_mapping(self,**options):
        self.mapping = options

    def parse_args(self,args=None,namespace=None):
        result = argparse.ArgumentParser.parse_args(self,args,namespace)
        for name,options in self.mapping.items(): #by default this is is empty so the loop is skipped
            if name in result:
                key = getattr(result,name)
                if key in options:
                    replace_with = options[key]
                    setattr(result,name,replace_with)
                else:
                    self.error("option {name!r} got invalid value: {key!r}\n must be one of {valid}".format(name=name,key=key,valid=tuple(options.keys())))
                    return #error should exit program but I'll leave this just to be safe.
        return result
```

this way the rest of your (example) program would look like this:

```
# There is nothing restricting their type.
CONST_A = "<something>"
CONST_B = ["other value", "type is irrelevent"]

parser = MappedParser() #constructor is same

parser.def_mapping(foo={"A":CONST_A, "B":CONST_B})

parser.add_argument("--foo") # and this is unchanged

# the following is now true:
print(parser.parse_args("--foo A".split()).foo is CONST_A)
print(parser.parse_args("--foo B".split()).foo is CONST_B)
#note that 'is' operator works so it is even the same reference

#this gives decent error message
parser.parse_args("--foo INVALID".split())

print("when parser.error() is called the program ends so this never is printed")
```

Add extra options like this:

```
parser.def_mapping(foo={"A":CONST_A, "B":CONST_B,"C":"third option"})
```

or extra arguments like this:

```
parser.def_mapping(foo={"A":CONST_A, "B":CONST_B},
                   conv={"int":int,"float":float})
```

as well any added arguments that are not specified in `def_mapping` are left alone so it is very easy to implement.

Comment: `MappedParser` was ok, **`argconv` is gold.**

Answer (score 4):

This is an interesting question. To the best of my knowledge, `argparse` does not support this directly.

If you find this pattern occurs often, you can write a small utility class that does this for you, by [transforming `args` into a dictionary via `vars`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16878315/what-is-the-right-way-to-treat-python-argparse-namespace-as-a-dictionary):

```
class Switcher(object):
    def __init__(self, d):
        self._d = d

    def __call__(self, args):
        args_ = vars(args)

        for k, v in self._d.items():
            if args_[k]:
                return v
```

You can use it as follows. Say your parser is defined by:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
g = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
g.add_argument('-a', action='store_true', default=False)
g.add_argument('-b', action='store_true', default=False)
```

Then you can define a `Switcher` via:

```
s = Switcher({'a': 10, 'b': 20})
```

and use it like so:

```
>>> print s(parser.parse_args(['-a']))
10 

>>> print s(parser.parse_args(['-b']))
20
```

Comment: This is a good alternative. If no one challenge you and points out a feature of `argparse` that _does_ support it directly, you'll get the green check!

Comment: sorry for stealing your accepted answer flag, I hope the credit for `argconv` is sufficient compensation :)

Comment: :-) Don't worry about it. Your answer is excellent - I'm upvoting it myself.

Answer (score 3):

This would be a good case for a custom `type` parameter:

```
CONST_A='<A>'
CONST_B='<B>'
def footype(astring):
    dd = {'A':CONST_A, 'B':CONST_B}
    try:
        return dd[astring]
    except KeyError:
        raise argparse.ArgumentTypeError('enter A or B')

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--foo', type=footype)
```

It will produce a namespace like

```
Namespace(foo='<A>')
```

and error message (if given `--foo C`) like:

```
usage: stack35648071.py [-h] [--foo FOO]
stack35648071.py: error: argument --foo: enter A or B
```

I tried adding `choices` but the help message isn't right.  Use `metavar` and `help` to instruct your users.

Comment: Thank you so much for posting this, I wouldn't have thought of `argconv` without you!

Comment: This is by far the best tactic although it does work better with a nested function then to hard code in the dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't create a new action or object: just use a `dict` to store the constants, limit the values of `--foo` with `choices` and use `parsed_args.foo` to index the `dict`:

```
import argparse

CONST = {'A': 'something',
         'B': 'otherthing'}

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--foo', choices=('A', 'B'))

assert CONST[parser.parse_args("--foo A".split()).foo] == 'something'
assert CONST[parser.parse_args("--foo B".split()).foo] == 'otherthing'
```

The combination of `choices` and the keys to the `dict` essentially fixes your results of `foo`.

---

And if you like to make things a bit clearer or easier, you can do reassign `foo` to your `dict` value after you parse the arguments:

```
args = parser.parse_args("--foo A".split())
args.foo = CONST[args.foo]
```

and now `args.foo` equates directly to `'something'`.

Comment: That's what I've ended up doing. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#action):

> The action keyword argument specifies how the command-line arguments should be handled. You may also specify an arbitrary action by passing an Action subclass or other object that implements the same interface.

```
In [5]: import argparse 
   ...:  
   ...: class MappingAction(argparse.Action): 
   ...:     def __init__(self, option_strings, dest, mapping, **kwargs): 
   ...:         self.mapping = mapping 
   ...:         super(MappingAction, self).__init__(option_strings, dest, **kwargs) 
   ...:  
   ...:     def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None): 
   ...:         values = self.mapping.get(values, None) 
   ...:         setattr(namespace, self.dest, values) 
   ...:                                                                                                                                                       

In [6]: parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()   
   ...: mapping = { 
   ...:     'A': '<something>', 
   ...:     'B': '<otherthing>', 
   ...: } 
   ...: parser.add_argument('bar', action=MappingAction, choices=mapping.keys(), mapping=mapping)                                                                                     

In [7]: args = parser.parse_args('A'.split())                                                                                                                 

In [8]: args.bar                                                                                                                                              
Out[8]: '<something>'
```