# Print effective arguments

Tags: python, argparse

I run a python program with a long argument list (> 20 arguments). Arguments have all a default values (if not overriden by user). At the program's startup, I print the effective argument to have a trace of how the program has been started. Today I print using a dumb routine:

```
def print_config(args):
    print("Configuration:")
    print("  shoes:   {}".format(args.shoes))
    print("  socket:  {}".format(args.socket))
    [...]
```

How can I print this using a smart iterator?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/16878315/3901060 for a way to make a dictionary out of `argparse`'s `Namespace` object. Then you can iterate over it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`args` is a `argparse.Namespace` object.  That class, or rather its `super` has a `repr` method.  That's what you see when you do

```
print(args)
```

The relevant lines of the `repr` (which you can find in the `argparse.py` file) are:

```
    arg_strings = []
    for name, value in sorted(self.__dict__.items()):
        arg_strings.append('%s=%r' % (name, value))
    return '%s(%s)' % (type_name, ', '.join(arg_strings))
```

If you joined with '\n' instead of ', ', it would give something close to your version.

`vars(args)` gives the same dictionary as `args.__dict__.items()`.

`print(parser.parse_args([]))` will show all the defaults, without any user input.  Of course that won't work if there are required inputs.