# Argparse. Funny issue with variable named "args"

Tags: python-3.x, argparse

I noticed one of my scripts was not running because an argparse parser was not able to parse_args().

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import argparse

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Save a plot to file")
    parser.add_argument('input_directory', metavar='i', type=str, default='.',
                        help='The input directory')

    parser.add_argument('output_file', metavar='o', type=str,
                        help='The output filename')

    parser.add_argument('--fix', type=str, default=None,
                        help='If FIX, the txt containing fix classification results')

    args = parser.parse_args()

    import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()
```

Strangely enough, I noticed that the problem has to do with the variable called `args`. I cannot retrieve any information from that variable, since it always returns empty.
If I change the name of the `args` variable to anything else, then the script works fine.

I'm asking this question because I could not find any information telling me that `args` is a keyword, or anything else.

I invoked my script as:

```
python3 plotter.py --fix $(pwd)/fix.txt $(pwd) $(pwd)/plot.png
```

Here's a screenshot of the funny behaviour:

[image: weird]

Note how any statement containing the word `args` does not return.

Any ideas of what may be happening here?

Comment: Does a plain `print(args)` work?  Maybe `ipdb` is using `args` for its own purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can refer to the `args` variable name by prepending it with an exclamation mark:

```
ipdb> !args
```

`args` is actually a command used by `ipdb`, see [here](https://wangchuan.github.io/coding/2017/07/12/ipdb-cheat-sheet.html):

**Explanation:**

```
a(rgs)
Print the argument list of the current function.
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using [vars()](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#vars)

```
args = vars(parser.parse_args())
```

then retrieve using

```
some_val = args['some']
```

Also refer this [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16878315/what-is-the-right-way-to-treat-python-argparse-namespace-as-a-dictionary)

Answer (score 1):

`ipdb/__main__.py` sets `args` in its `main`:

```
def main():
    ...
    opts, args = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:], 'hc:', ['--help', '--command='])
```

I don't know what's visible when run interactively, but I suspect its own use of `args` is interfering with what you see with

```
args = parser.parse_args(...)
```

When testing `argparse`, I routinely add a

```
print(args)
```

statement.  Or I test it in an `ipython` session, where I can look at the result of `parse_args` without further work.