# Python: How to make command line arguments available for objects?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am relatively new to Python and I am trying to solve the following problem at the moment. I am writing a script which parses command line arguments with argparse. Besides some other things I have a verbosity flag, which I want to make available for some objects. Currently I am passing it to the constructor and I am wondering if there is a more elegant way for doing this.

```
class MyClass(object):

    def __init__(self, verbosity=False):
        self.verbosity = verbosity

    def do_something(self):
        if self.verbosity:
            print("Doing something ...")
```

.

```
import argparse
import myclass

def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Testing.')
    parser.add_argument('-v', '--verbosity', action='store_true',
                    help="Produce verbose output")
    args = parser.parse_args()
    object = myclass.MyClass(verbosity=args.verbosity)
    object.do_something()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Any help would really be appreciated.

Comment: Not entirely sure what you mean by "elegant" but if you're using several command line arguments you could pass the `args` object to your constructor and have the constructor set flags/call methods based on the arguments instead of passing each argument separately.

Answer (score 0):

I would say what you're doing is the cleanest approach, at least in this simple case. You could pass the `args` namespace that `argparse` gives you to the `MyClass` initializer, but then you'll need to construct a similar object if you want to run tests on your class, or to use it as a library from another script.

If you want the same command line options to be available from multiple classes or scripts, you could create a `config.py` that looks something like this:

```
import argparse

__all__ = ['options']

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Testing.')
parser.add_argument('-v', '--verbosity', action='store_true',
                        help="Produce verbose output")
args = parser.parse_args()
options = vars(args)
```

Then from your script you can do `from config import options` and get the parsed argument from `options['verbosity']`. You could also change the value of options - for something like:

```
if self.too_much_output():
    options['verbosity'] = False
```

and have that change be available to any code that's using `options`.

(The idea to use `vars(args)` comes from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16878364/9200529) to another argparse-related question.)

Comment: Thank you! I was looking for something like the `config.py` solution, but unfortunately I have not only one script where I'd like to use it. Therefore I'd stay with my current solution for now.

Comment: @janno - I don't understand your objection: you could use this from any number of scripts, or from just one. If you put it in your PYTHONPATH you could use it from anywhere!

Comment: To be clear, when I say could "change the value of options", that would only take effect for a single process.

Comment: Well, it's a bunch of scripts with different command line arguments. Sorry for missing this detail in my first comment.