# Passing positional arguments to functions

Tags: python, python-2.7, argparse

I'm writing a module that can be accessed from an import directly as well as from the command line using `argparse`.
How can I allow my functions to work for both `argparse` and general module imports? Argparse requires me to use something like:

```python
import argparse 

def foo(args):
  arg1 = args.arg1
  arg2 = args.arg2

if __name__ == '__main__':
  parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
  subparsers = parser.add_subparsers()

  parser_foo = subparsers.add_parser('foo')
  parser_foo.add_argument('arg1')
  parser_foo.add_argument('arg2')
  parser_foo.set_defaults(func=foo)
  args = parser.parse_args()
  args.func(args)
```

But if I import this module, I cannot just input one argument "`args`" for everything.

I thought of using just `**kwargs` to receive the arguments (passing the `argparse` arguments as `vars(**args)`), but I'm not sure if this is good practice.

```python
def foo(**kwargs):
  arguments = {
    arg1 = None,
    arg2 = None,
  }
  arguments.update(**kwargs)

  arg1 = arguments['arg1']
  arg2 = arguments['arg2']
```

Then, every time I use the functions from the imported module I have to use key worded arguments.

```
foo(arg1='value1',arg2='value2')
```

What would be a better way to approach this?

Is there a way to pass positional arguments using argparse? So when the module is imported, one can do

```
foo('value1','value2')
```

**EDIT**

I thought of another possible solution

```
def foo(arg1=None,arg2=None):
  pass
```

This way the function would accept both kwargs and args. Good/bad practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [vars()](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#vars) to get a dictionary from your Namespace. Here is a simple example:

```
import argparse


def introduce(name, age):
    print '{} is {} years old'.format(name, age)


def handle_parameters():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('name', type=str)
    parser.add_argument('age', type=int)
    return parser.parse_args()


def main():
    args = handle_parameters()

    introduce(**vars(args))
    introduce('john', 10)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

If you have a lot of arguments or if you don't like this solution you can create your own Namespace and pass only one argument (the namespace) to your function as described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16878315/what-is-the-right-way-to-treat-python-argparse-namespace-as-a-dictionary).

Hope it helps.