# How to store an 'args.foo' value to a 'bar' variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

I have been using the [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) for my latest project and although it is extremely helpful, I have realized that most of the time, especially in longer scripts, I try to avoid using the variable with the 'args.' prefix, so lines like this are bloating my code:

```
parser.add_argument('--learning_rate', '--lr', default=0.0005, type=float, help='defines the learning_rate variable for the model.')
learning_rate = args.learning_rate
```

is there an option to automatically store the content passed to `--learning_rate` into `learning_rate`, avoiding this second line of code?

Thanks for your time and attention.

Comment: You can just use `args.learning_rate`. That is automatic. Why copy it to another reference if you don't want it?

Comment: "I try to avoid using the variable with the 'args.' prefix" Why?

Comment: You can modify the global scope, but you **really shouldn't**, "Namespaces are one honking great idea -- let's do more of those!". You can't do this in local scopes. But again, that's not an issue, because you *really probably shouldn't*

Comment: I think the key is, you *don't* want to be scattering `args.learning_rate` in *local* scopes. Use `args.learning_rate` in the scope where  `args` was defined, but if you need the value in a function, don't use `args` as a global: pass `args.learning_rate` as an *argument* to the function, which will perform an implicit assignment to the function's parameter when you make the call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have said, removing the line referencing `args.learning_rate` will lead to others finding your code cryptic or confusing.

But something like this could be used in code golfing, so I will offer a 'cryptic' way of doing this under the assumption that you have several arguments that you do not want to have to reassign line-by-line.

You could acquire the dictionary of `args` using the `vars()` built-in function or `__dict__` attribute.
Please reference [What is the right way to treat Python argparse.Namespace() as a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16878315/what-is-the-right-way-to-treat-python-argparse-namespace-as-a-dictionary).

```
>>> import argparse
>>> args = argparse.Namespace()
>>> args.foo = 1
>>> args.bar = [1,2,3]
>>> d = vars(args)
>>> d
{'foo': 1, 'bar': [1, 2, 3]}
```

Afterwards you could convert these keys to variables and assign the values to the variable like so:

```
for k, v in d.items():
    exec(f'{k} = {v}')
print(foo) # 1
print(bar) # [1, 2, 3]
```

Please see [Using a string variable as a variable name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11553721/using-a-string-variable-as-a-variable-name) for additional insight to why `exec()` may be bad practice and `setattr` may be more appropriate ***if*** you resort to this method.

Answer (score 1):

When you call a function, an argument is implicitly assigned to a parameter.

In the same scope where `args` is defined, I would continue using `args.learning_rate` to emphasize that it is a configuration option. But instead of writing

```
def foo(x):
    return x * args.learning_rate

y = foo(3)
```

write

```
def foo(x, learning_rate):
    return x * learning_rate

y = foo(args.learning_rate)
```

When reading the definition of `foo`, you don't care how `learning_rate` will be set at call time.